# Apply Fp-growth algorithm in R studio for transaction data set to generate association rules

Tags: r, data-mining

Fp-growth algorithm can be applied in R for iris data set as follows.

```html
library("rJava")
library("rCBA")
data("iris")
train <- sapply(iris,as.factor)
train <- data.frame(train, check.names=FALSE)
txns <- as(train,"transactions")
rules = rCBA::fpgrowth(txns, support=0.03, confidence=0.03, maxLength=1, consequent="Species", parallel=FALSE)
inspect(rules)
```

But it doesn't work for transaction data. How Fp- growth algorithm is used in R for transaction data set like below?

[image]

Comment: What is the error? Fpgrowth on Iris does not make sense... Why don't you use the arules package?